# How do I filter DateTime by specific Month and/or Day in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am looking for a way to get Users from Graph API whose CreatedDateTime are equal to a specific Month and Days are in range of 1st to DateTime.Now.Day. So for example:

- I want to get users whose accounts were created in May and today is 2022.03.17 so the response I am looking for will be users who have CreatedDateTime Month == 5 and CreatedDateTime Day is between 1st and 17th and the year of creation does not matter.

Documentation says requests support ODataV4, I tried to filter my request like this:

- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=month(createdDateTime) eq 5 and day(createdDateTime) lt 18

month() and day() odatav4 operators seem to not be supported, adding ConsistencyLevel = eventual header does not help.

Is there any way I can filter Dates in Graph API just by specific months/days, ignoring year?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) `createdDateTime` supports `$filter` with the following operators:

`eq`, `ne`, `not`, `ge`, `le` and `in`